# ASP.NET Core - MapFallbackToFile() with condition based on subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I have a YARP gateway that serves static SPA files.

```cs
//...
app.MapReverseProxy();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
//...
```

Now I need to serve another bundle of static SPA files for a specific subdomain.

So if hostname starts with for example `admin.` (never mind the domain) I need to serve the `index.html` inside `wwwroot/admin`, otherwise I need to serve the `index.html` inside `wwwroot` (which I can move to another folder as well).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me, it's based on the `MapFallbackToFile()` [source code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/StaticFilesEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs,10c00861ffd18b9f).

```cs
app.MapFallback(CreateRequestDelegate(app, "index.html"))
   .WithMetadata(new HttpMethodMetadata(new[] { HttpMethods.Get, HttpMethods.Head }));

static RequestDelegate CreateRequestDelegate(
    IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints,
    string filePath,
    StaticFileOptions? options = null)
{
    var app = endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder();
    app.Use(next => context =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Host.Host.StartsWith("admin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            filePath = "admin/" + filePath;
        }

        context.Request.Path = "/" + filePath;

        // Set endpoint to null so the static files middleware will handle the request.
        context.SetEndpoint(null);

        return next(context);
    });

    if (options == null)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles(options);
    }

    return app.Build();
}
```

The problem with @Guru's answer was that it made the browser to download the HTML file instead of rendering it.

Comment: JIC there where other options suggested, have you tried `app.MapFallbackToFile("/admin/{**slug}", "admin/index.html");` approach?

Comment: I needed to serve files on a subdomain (admin.example.com), so the route template options were no applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `MapFallback` overload which accepts the fallback delegate which will return needed file:

```cs
app.MapFallback((HttpContext ctx, CancellationToken ct) =>
{
    string path;
    if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(...))
    {
        path = "..."
    }
    else
    {
        path = "..."
    }
    
    return Results.File(path);
});
```

Or use `MapFallbackToFile` overload accepting pattern:

```cs
app.MapFallbackToFile("/admin/{**slug}", "admin/index.html");
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

Or try using the ability to conditionally branch the execution pipeline with `UseWhenExtensions.UseWhen` (not sure that it will work though):

> Conditionally creates a branch in the request pipeline that is rejoined to the main pipeline.

```cs
app.UseWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(...), // predicate to determine that compression should be used 
    appCond => 
   {
       appCond.UseStaticFiles();
       appCond.UseRouting();
       appCond.MapFallbackToFile("index.html")
   });
```

Comment: "appCond" does not contain a definition for 'MapFallbackToFile'

Comment: @Parsa99 you are right. Try something like `app.UseWhen(context => ..., aptOptIn => aptOptIn.UseEndpoints(routeBuilder => routeBuilder.MapFallbackToFile("")));`.

Comment: This got me an exception

Comment: @Parsa99 which one exactly?

Comment: @Parsa99 also see the another suggestion.